# Why are my cloned datatable rows not appearing in a data grid?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datatable, copy

I cannot copy rows from one datatable to another (from clonedt to clonedt2)

First of all metode read the excel file to table dt

I clone dt to clonedt to get proper type of data.
Because i need only 3 columns from clonedt i clone again and I copy the rows.

Unfortunately nothing appear in data grid apart from column header.

When I change clonedt to dt table is copied with no problem.

First of all metode read the excel file to table dt

I clone dt to clonedt to get proper type of data.
Because i need only 3 columns from clonedt i clone again and I copy the rows.

Unfortunately nothing appear in data grid apart from column header.

When I change clonedt to dt table is copied with no problem.

```
Private Sub AgrestLoadXL()

        Dim dt As System.Data.DataTable = ReadDataExcel(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "FlANGEDATA6.xls"))

        Dim clonedDT As System.Data.DataTable = dt.Clone
        clonedDT.Columns("NB ('')").DataType = GetType(Double)
        clonedDT.Columns("NB (mm)").DataType = GetType(Double)
        clonedDT.Columns("STD").DataType = GetType(String)
        clonedDT.Columns("RATING").DataType = GetType(String)
        clonedDT.Columns("OD").DataType = GetType(Double)
        clonedDT.Columns("PCD").DataType = GetType(Double)
        clonedDT.Columns("No Bolts").DataType = GetType(Double)
        clonedDT.Columns("Thk Steel").DataType = GetType(Double)
        clonedDT.Columns("RF Dia").DataType = GetType(Double)
        clonedDT.Columns("RTJ RF Dia").DataType = GetType(Double)
        clonedDT.Columns("RF DIP").DataType = GetType(Double)
        clonedDT.Columns("RTJ DIP").DataType = GetType(String)
        clonedDT.Columns("RF Height").DataType = GetType(Double)
        clonedDT.Columns("RF RTJ Height").DataType = GetType(Double)
        clonedDT.Columns("Hole Size").DataType = GetType(String)
        clonedDT.Columns("Bolt Metric").DataType = GetType(String)
        clonedDT.Columns("Bolt Inch").DataType = GetType(String)
        clonedDT.Columns("Ring type & Size").DataType = GetType(String)
        clonedDT.Columns("RF").DataType = GetType(Double)
        clonedDT.Columns("RTJ").DataType = GetType(Double)
        clonedDT.Columns("RTJRing Gap").DataType = GetType(String)
        clonedDT.Columns("Thk Iron").DataType = GetType(String)
        clonedDT.Columns("PipeOD").DataType = GetType(Double)

        Dim clonedDT2 As System.Data.DataTable

        clonedDT2 = clonedDT.DefaultView.ToTable(True, "NB ('')", "RATING", "STD")
        CopyColumns(clonedDT, clonedDT2, "NB ('')", "RATING", "STD")


        WPFinstance.myDataGrid.DataContext = clonedDT2
        REDDATA = WPFinstance.myDataGrid.DataContext
        ALLDATA = clonedDT
    End Sub
    Private Sub CopyColumns(ByVal source As System.Data.DataTable, ByVal dest As System.Data.DataTable, ParamArray columns As String())
        For Each sourcerow As DataRow In source.Rows
            Dim destRow As DataRow = dest.NewRow()

            For Each colname As String In columns
                destRow(colname) = sourcerow(colname)
            Next

            dest.Rows.Add(destRow)
        Next
    End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pni2X.jpg)

Comment: Why do you assign the DataTable to the DataContext of the DataGrid? You must assign it to the ItemsSource of the DataGrid.

Comment: Once I assign the data table to item source the application crash with error'unable to cast object of type systemdatatable to type system.collections.IEnumerable, anyway it is not problem with datacontext.

Comment: You must  assign the default view, of course: `dataGrid.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;`. Assigning the table to the DAtaContext won't make the DataGrid show the data.